# Add up values from a text file

Tags: java, file-io, sum, bufferedreader

Hi Guys I have a text file that contains Amounts at Substring (34, 47) of each line. I need to sum Up all the Values to the End of the File. I have this code that I had started to build but I do not know how to proceed from here:

```
public class Addup {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    // TODO code application logic here
    FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream("C:/Analysis/RL004.TXT");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs));
    String line;
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
        String num = line.substring(34, 47);

        double i = Double.parseDouble(num);
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
}
```

The output is like this:

```
1.44576457E4
2.33434354E6
4.56875685E3
```

The Amount is in two decimal Places and I need the result also in the Two decimal Places. What Is the Best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DecimalFormat` is the best option to use:

```
double roundTwoDecimals(double d) {
            DecimalFormat twoDForm = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
        return Double.valueOf(twoDForm.format(d));
}
```

You can change your code to :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    // TODO code application logic here
    double sum = 0.0;
    FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream("C:/Analysis/RL004.TXT");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs));
    String line;
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
        String num = line.substring(34, 47);

        double i = Double.parseDouble(num);
        sum = sum + i;
        DecimalFormat twoDForm = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
        System.out.println(Double.valueOf(twoDForm.format(i)));
    }
        System.out.println("SUM = " + Double.valueOf(twoDForm.format(sum)));
}
}
```

Comment: How about adding up the Amounts?

Comment: Added sum part.I think after adding all the values only you should truncate the sum. You should not truncate all individual values and then add them ,since this can make the big difference.

Comment: The decinal format function still gives me the same Output for the very large Amounts

Comment: I combined the your code and the format String Format from Liu Yan as the decimal format function gives the same output with E6656 at the End Thank you am voting for this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Or, use `String.format` to format the double value.

```
System.out.println (String.format("%1.2f", i));
```

Comment: Thankz Liu Yan I combined the String.format and the Suggested method by vikiiii and I got the desired Output